# Create a back to top button for website

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a back-to-top button such as this example (http://www.meanthemes.com/plugins/meanmenu/, Scroll down and you'll view the back to top button on your right) and I can't seem to get it working.

Can anyone help me out in showing me how to create one and only triggering the button's display when the user scrolls down at least 20% of the page.

Thank you.

Comment: It is working for me. I am on Chrome Version 30.0.1599.0

Comment: try this http://jsfiddle.net/zrVPJ/4/ with jquery

Comment: jQuery forever!  Actually, give the header (or wherever you want to scroll to) an ID, then post a link redirecting to that ID on the page, such as: http://yourdomain.com#ID_name.  Use the # sign between the domain and ID name to specify what the last bit is. I took an HTML5 class and my teacher made me do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the following jQuery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            // Show or hide the sticky footer button
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200) {
                    $('.go-top').fadeIn(200);
                } else {
                    $('.go-top').fadeOut(200);
                }
            });

            // Animate the scroll to top
            $('.go-top').click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();

                $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 300);
            })
        });
```

check [this tutorial](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-implement-a-sticky-back-to-top-button/) for more info

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery scrollTop to display the button .
Here is the link this may help you .

http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/07/using-jquery-to-add-a-dynamic-back-to-top-floating-button-with-smooth-scroll/

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var offset = 220;
var duration = 500;
jQuery(window).scroll(function() {
    if (jQuery(this).scrollTop() > offset) {
        jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeIn(duration);
    } else {
        jQuery('.back-to-top').fadeOut(duration);
    }
});

jQuery('.back-to-top').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    jQuery('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, duration);
    return false;
})
});
```

Comment: always excerpt some of the code from a linked answer - otherwise your answer looks spammy and may be deleted.

Comment: Hi there, I know its old topic and this answer works for me aswell but do u know why I need to refresh the page to display the button? the button it comes visible right after refresh

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
function gotoTop()
{
$('body,html').animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
}
</script>
<a href=javascript:void(0); onclick=gotoTop();>Top</a>
```